# Mass assignment in Rails 4 with array setter method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I've been making and following an acts_as_taggable + Jquery Input token tutorial and since I'm doing this in Rails 4. I can't make mass assignments to work with this:

```
class TagCategory < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_taggable

  attr_reader :tag_list_tokens
  attr_accessible :name, :tag_list_tokens

  def tag_list_tokens=(tokens)
    self.tag_list = tokens.gsub("'", "")
  end
end
```

So since in Rails 4, strong params are used then I have coded it in my controller:

```
def tag_categories_params
   params.require(:tag_category).permit(:name, :tag_list_tokens => [])
end
```

Now, my problem is with this part of the code:

```
def tag_list_tokens=(tokens)
    self.tag_list = tokens.gsub("'", "")
end
```

How do I create one in Rails 4 to mass assign values to a certain field? Thanks! :)

Comment: did you ever figure this out? thanks